# проблема с hibernate (transactionManager) в связке со springMVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

---

- Элемент списка

1

```
Error occurred during deployment:
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-context.xml]:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sesionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sesionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-context.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V. Please see server.log for more details.
```

2

```
Error occurred during deployment: 
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service':
Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sesionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-context.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V. Please see server.log for more details.
```

app-conext.xml

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pn"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="tuha"/>


    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses" value="com.springapp.model.model"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.controller"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.service"/> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

использую spring 4.1.1 и hibernate 4
переставлял в настройках {mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml и app-context.xml} все что в голову приходило но нет толку.
в основном ошибка происходит
при создании бина transactionManager мол проперти не правильный или что-то вроде этого.у sessionFactory проблемы с инит методом.
из-за чего это может быть?помогите пожалуйста.

0
голос против

### accept

вот класс модель

```
    package com.springapp.model;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; 
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType; 
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity 
    public class model {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 
    private String name; 
    private String last;

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
     }
}
```

Comment: код покажете или секрет ;)?

Comment: еще раз... в коде поищите "sesionFactory"

Comment: глянул бин `sessionFactory` Единственно отличие в том, что  у меня вместо `annotatedClasses` используется `packagesToScan`.

Comment: старался отформатировать.не смог.как нибудь научусь.справочник не сильно помог.

Comment: @Ben Выделить код и нажать `Ctrl + K`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не в TransactionManager дело. Пробема вот с этим

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

У Вас в classpath присутствует некорректная весия библиотеки jboss-logging-xxx.jar. Эта библиотека могла появится как транзистивная зависимость Maven, или быть в каталоге с библиотеками сервера приложений или веб-контейнера.

Подробнее можно почитать здесь

[Hibernate 5 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547015/hibernate-5-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logging-logger-debugf)

Только версия должна быть для Hibernate 4, а не Hibernate 5, конечно.

Comment: хотел остальной код поставить сюда.сейчас с телефона сижу.(жуткий старый не удобный телефон)интернета нет уже день.класс model аннотирован.менял в коде все что приходило в голову.попробую вот этот вариант с логгером.потом отпишусь.сейчас и света нет.эл/во отрубили.

Comment: @Ben В Крыму что-ли? :) Здесь не в коде дело. Вам надо pom.xml смотреть и библиотеки, которые ваш сервер приложений подхватывает (у него где-то есть дефолтные библиотеки, которые он использует в дополнение к вашим).

Comment: не не в крыму ))). бишкек.сейчас попробую.

Comment: интернет включили и эл/во тоже.

Comment: @Ben Классно, у вас девушки красивые :)

Comment: спс.не красивые тоже есть.